# How To Upload An Image using Corona SDK Lua

Tags: php, lua, coronasdk

I am creating a social app with PHP and corona sdk (Lua)(something like Instagram) . One of the option that the user has is to upload a picture from their phone and use it as a profile picture on their account .

I have no idea how to upload a picture to a folder inside my folder where the app is and then show that picture on the users profile . I've looked at tutorials but they didn't help me.  Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

You question description is too wide. Be specific about your question. I imagine you are asking to upload image from Corona SDK as your question title.

Here is image uploading to server from Corona SDK.

1 - Image selection from Gallery.

```
-- Selection completion listener
local function onComplete( event )
    local photo = event.target

    if photo then
        print( "photo w,h = " .. photo.width .. "," .. photo.height )
    end
end

local button = display.newRect( 120, 240, 80, 70 )

local function pickPhoto( event )

    media.selectPhoto(
    {
        mediaSource = media.SavedPhotosAlbum,
        listener = onComplete, 
        origin = button.contentBounds, 
        permittedArrowDirections = { "right" },
        destination = { baseDir=system.TemporaryDirectory, filename="image.jpg" } 
    })
end

button:addEventListener( "tap", pickPhoto )
```

Corona doc for [media.selectPhoto](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/selectPhoto.html)

2 - Uploading image to server.

You need MultipartFormData library added into your project. Here is [Link](https://github.com/benglard/Augment/blob/master/App/class_MultipartFormData.lua)

Then

```
local MultipartFormData = require("class_MultipartFormData")
local multipart = MultipartFormData.new()
local path=system.pathForFile( "image.jpg", system.TemporaryDirectory )
multipart:addFile("Image", path, "image/jpg", "image.jpg")

local params = {}        
params.body = multipart:getBody()
params.headers = multipart:getHeaders() -- Headers not valid until getBody() is called.

network.request("https://your.server.url/services/imageupload?parameter=1", "POST", listener, params)
```

You can pass parameters to url too after a ?. Check the url.

Comment: How do I search for an image on the phone . Like how it is on the when where you have the choose file button , you choose the image and upload it ?

Comment: Do you want to select image from phone gallery or camera roll?

Comment: Where do I put the second part of your answer in my code ?

Comment: What must I do on the PHP side ?

Comment: it give me error
ERROR: Runtime error
                    module 'class_MultipartFormData' not found:
                     no field package.preload['class_MultipartFormData']
                     no file '/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/Corona/Simulator/Plugins/class_MultipartFormData.lua'
                     no file 'class_MultipartFormData.lua'

Comment: @mohammadalabid You should add class_MultipartFormData into your project. Please search on google class_MultipartFormData and add into root path of project where main.lua exists.